# How to convert a Matrix into a Vector of Vectors?

Tags: julia

I have the following matrix `A = [1.00 2.00; 3.00 4.00]` and I need to convert it into a vector of Vectors as follows:

`A1 = [1.00; 3.00]
 A2 = [2.00; 4.00]`

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want a vector of vectors or separate objects for each vector?  Your text indicators the former, your code illustration indicates the latter.

Comment: Also, can you give context on why you would need this?  In almost every case I can think of, you'd be better just referencing the columns while they are still in your matrix or at most, creating separate views of them with `sub()`, e.g. `B = sub(A, 1:size(A,2),1)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**tl;dr**
This can be very elegantly created with a list comprehension:

```
A = [A[:,i] for i in 1:size(A,2)]
```

---

Explanation:

This essentially converts `A` from something that would be indexed as `A[1,2]` to something that would be indexed as `A[2][1]`, which is what you asked.

Here I'm assigning directly back to `A`, which seems to me what you had in mind. But, only do this if the code is unambiguous! *It's generally not a good idea to have same-named variables that represent different things at different points in the code*.

**NOTE**: if this *reversal* of row / column order in the indexing isn't the order you had in mind, and you'd prefer `A[1,2]` to be indexed as `A[1][2]`, then perform your list comprehension 'per row' instead, i.e.

```
A = [A[i,:] for i in 1:size(A,1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

It's even simpler.

`eachcol` is all you need. It's an abstract vector.

```
A=eachcol(A)
```

Now `A[1]` is `[1.00; 3.00]`, and `A[2]` is `[2.00; 4.00]`.

With this approach, there are no memory allocations. Everything is based on views.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much better simply to use slices of your matrix i.e. instead of A1 use
`A[:,1]`
and instead of A2 use
`A[:,2]`

If you really need them to be "seperate" objections you could try creating a cell array like so:

`myfirstcell = cell(size(A,2))
for i in 1:size(A,2)
    myfirstcell[i] = A[:,i]
end`

See http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/arrays/#Base.cell

(Cell arrays allow several different types of object to be stored in the same array)

Comment: You could at least have an Array of Arrays explicitly, without needing to use `cell` `A_vec = Array{Array{eltype(A),1}, size(A,2)}`

Comment: Agreed, the accepted answer is still much better though!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `B = [eachcol(A)...]`. This returns an variable with type `Vector{SubArray}` which might be fine depending on what you want to do. To get a `Vector{Vector{Float64}}` try,

```
B = Vector{eltype(A)}[eachcol(A)...]
```